# Plasma: Windows go behind panel (no multiple screens)

Tags: kubuntu, monitor, panel, plasma

I'm using Kubuntu 16.04. After installing the latest updates, some system settings appear to have been reset.

My problem now is that windows go behind the plasma panel (located at the top). This happens despite the option "always visible" is marked. I tried other options as well, other screen edges (it seems to work when the panel is located on the right side), but that doesn't help when I switch back.

I don't use multiple screens and didn't experience this issue before. When I change the display resolution, the problem is gone but reappears when I change it back.

A screenshot of the problem is added

[image: problem picture]

Comment: can you give us a screenshot?

Comment: @Anwar here you go: [link](https://abload.de/img/screenfdsr0.png)

Comment: Why is your panel at the Top? You changed it or it was by default? Kubuntu has panel at bottom

Comment: @Answar I prefer it that way so I changed it. It has never been a problem

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it's working now after I played around with the panel settings again. I don't know why it's working now. I did update-apt-xapian-index earlier to get my Driver Manager working again, don't know if that's got anything to do with it.