# Kubuntu 16.04 Windows go behind panel after upgrade

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I got exactly the same problem as [Plasma: Windows go behind panel (no multiple screens)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813373/plasma-windows-go-behind-panel-no-multiple-screens/813503#813503?newreg=c4a92da80c964ba78e803e9e57c81b3a)

after unidentified upgrade (one of following)

```
Start-Date: 2016-12-16  09:32:54
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libapt-inst2.0:amd64 (1.2.15, 1.2.15ubuntu0.2), apt:amd64 (1.2.15, 1.2.15ubuntu0.2), flashplugin-installer:amd64 (11.2.202.644ubuntu0.16.04.1, 24.0.0.186ubuntu0.16.04.1), libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 (1.2.15, 1.2.15ubuntu0.2), apport:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.4), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.4), firefox-locale-en:amd64 (50.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 50.1.0+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libgme0:amd64 (0.6.0-3, 0.6.0-3ubuntu0.16.04.1), apt-utils:amd64 (1.2.15, 1.2.15ubuntu0.2), firefox:amd64 (50.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 50.1.0+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), apt-transport-https:amd64 (1.2.15, 1.2.15ubuntu0.2), apport-kde:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.4), python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.4)
End-Date: 2016-12-16  09:34:03

Start-Date: 2016-12-17  09:34:32
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libavdevice-ffmpeg56:amd64 (7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7:2.8.10-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), ffmpeg:amd64 (7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7:2.8.10-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libavutil-ffmpeg54:amd64 (7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7:2.8.10-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libavfilter-ffmpeg5:amd64 (7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7:2.8.10-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libswresample-ffmpeg1:amd64 (7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7:2.8.10-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libpostproc-ffmpeg53:amd64 (7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7:2.8.10-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libswscale-ffmpeg3:amd64 (7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7:2.8.10-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libavresample-ffmpeg2:amd64 (7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7:2.8.10-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libavcodec-ffmpeg56:amd64 (7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7:2.8.10-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libavformat-ffmpeg56:amd64 (7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7:2.8.10-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
End-Date: 2016-12-17  09:34:42

Start-Date: 2016-12-20  09:01:57
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3), samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3), libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3)
End-Date: 2016-12-20  09:02:02
```

I use almost default settings, but panel on top. 
Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution after inspecting of everything. In <kbd>Display and monitor</kbd>→<kbd>Display configuration</kbd> something evil changed <kbd>Primary display</kbd> to <kbd>No primary output</kbd>. After change to <kbd>Laptop screen</kbd> the issue disappears.